# how to create ear file in jdeveloper

Tags: java, deployment, oracle-adf, ear, jdeveloper

I have two fusion web applications in oracle adf (jdeveloper):

1. LoginApp
2. InventoryApp

To share session between this two applications I have enabled session sharing in both applications.

weblogic-application.xml:

```
<session-descriptor>
  <sharing-enabled>true</sharing-enabled>
</session-descriptor>
```

Now to share session between the two applications I have found that I needs to create a `ear` file. So my question is that how to create `.ear` file containing two applications.

Answer (score 2):

Package one app to be included in the other app.
(Read about ADF libraries for this).
Then create the EAR from the containing app deployment options.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial should explain what you are asking. The first link: [Dependent ADF project](http://hasamali.blogspot.com/2011/04/jdeveloper-adf-project-as-dependent.html) describes how to pack ADF applications as libraries. While the second: [Create EAR](http://hasamali.blogspot.com/2011/04/jdevelopercreate-ear-project-based-on.html), uses the output from the first part to create the `.ear`